# Grep patterns in selected lines

Tags: grep

How to keep rows containing `pattern 1` only if the next line contains `pattern 2` and starts with `pattern 3` ?

Exemple: keep line starting with an `A` only if the next line starts with a `B` and contains the pattern `B1`

Input file

```
A   item1A
B   item1B2
A   item2A
A   item3A
B   item3B1
B   item3CB1
B   item3B2
A   item5A
B   item5B1
A   item6A
```

Expected output:

```
A   item3A
B   item3B1
B   item3CB1
A   item5A
B   item5B1
```

( I'm currently trying with `grep -e ^A -e B1` but the side effect is that all `A` s lines are kept )

Comment: Please clarify why the third line of your expected output is there? The preceding line doesn't contain the letter `A`.

Comment: Because that condition is on line starting with an A ("keep line starting with A only if the next line starts with a B and contains the pattern B1"). The only condition for lines starting with B is that they must contain pattern B1... (I'm not sure my verbal explanation is clear enough...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '^(A.*\n)?B.*B1'
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  /^B.*B1/ {if (p && last ~ /^A/) print last; print; p=0; next}
  {p=1; last=$0}'
```

Comment: But this method isn't printing the A lines...